# Get UIView from CGRect using UIPanGestureRecognizer - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm working on an app that uses the **UIPanGesturerecognizer** to **move** a **UIView**. I have **3** more **views** on my Screen, more **fixed**.

The view that I will drag with the gesture, is in the color **blue**. The first view is fixed with the **orange** color. The second view is fixed with **green** color. The third view is fixed to the **Purple** color.

[image]

My actual Swift code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var panView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        panView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panViewGesture:"))
    }

    func panViewGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let locationInView = sender.locationInView(self.view)

        if sender.state == .Changed {

            panView.frame.origin = locationInView

        }

    }

}
```

**My Problem**:

When the **View Blue** is on the **View Orange**, the **View Orange** should change the background color to blue, like the 'View Blue'.

The same happens with the **View Green** and **View Purple**.

---

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to make a function that recognizes from CGRect data which is the view from below and returns a UIView.

Returning to UIView, I can easily change the background color.

---

**What I need?**

I need a syntax that can make the recognition of view overlapped while using the UIPanGestureRecognizer to drag another UIView

---

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this modified code :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var panView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        panView.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "panViewGesture:"))
    }

    func panViewGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let locationInView = sender.locationInView(self.view)

        if sender.state == .Changed {

            panView.center = locationInView

            if let view  = intersectingViewWithView(panView) {
                view.backgroundColor = panView.backgroundColor
            }
        }

    }


    func intersectingViewWithView(panView: UIView) -> UIView? {
        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if view != panView {
                if CGRectIntersectsRect(panView.frame, view.frame) {
                    return view
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```